# User Input of sentence in Java

Tags: java, string, java.util.scanner

Whenever I use sc.nextLine in java I get this error. It skips one line. Anybody knows how to fix it. sc.nextLine fails for multiple test cases as takes skips one line and then take input. Anybody knows another way to take sentence input in java?

**For Input:**

```
2
geeksforgeeks
geeks for geeks
```

**your output is:**

```
geeksforgeeks
```

Code:

```
class GFG {
    public static void main (String[] args) 
    {
        Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
        int testcases=sc.nextInt();
        while(testcases--!=0)
        {
            String str=sc.nextLine();
            System.out.println(str);
        }
        //code
    }
}
```

Comment: read a line after ***int testcases=sc.nextInt();*** because readin the Int from scanner is not reading a lineTermination chars....

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you have to read a line after `int testcases=sc.nextInt();` because reading the Int from scanner is not reading a line Termination chars....

```
public static void main (String[] args) 
{
    Scanner sc=new Scanner(System.in);
    int testcases=sc.nextInt();
    sc.nextLine();  //<--HERE!
    while(testcases--!=0)
    {
        String str=sc.nextLine();
        System.out.println(str);
    }
```